# How can I Forward an Email to FogBugz and Have it Make it into a Bug?

Tags: email, fogbugz

I didn't see it in the help but I figure it's possible.  Also how do I find out what email address to use?

Answer (score 9):

Have you looked [here](http://help.fogcreek.com/7754/using-fogbugz-to-check-pop3-and-imap-mailboxes)?

<sup>Updated link to new help desk 2013/10/7</sup>

Comment: What do I write in the email to assign it to someone, how will it handle attachments?

Comment: I don't remember exactly since I haven't used FogBugz in a while.  I remember it was supposed to have a "smart" filter and would sort automatically based on the subject.  Since the question is specific to FogBugz, I'd check the FogBugz forums at http://support.fogcreek.com/?fogbugz

Comment: It will handle attachments. Who the email gets assigned to depends on how the mailbox is set up in FogBugz.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using FogBugz-on-Demand, chances are you have a cases@<your-account-name>.fogbugz.com address that already works.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jonathan said, you must first setup a mailbox for the project. See his link for details. Then you simply forward to the address you created for the project. We typically use addresses like product-support@company.com.